# How do I deal with a seemingly fractional delays in discrete time fourier transforms?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Is a transfer function of a discrete time system is $H(e^{j\Omega})=e^{-j\Omega/4}$ and I feed it an impulse, what will be it's response? I know that technically a transfer function of $e^{j{\Omega}n_0}$ represents a delay of $n_0$ samples. What happens if the delay is fractional?

Answer (score 2):

Simply compute the inverse discrete-time Fourier transform:

$$h(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}H(e^{j\Omega})e^{jn\Omega}d\Omega$$

With $H(e^{j\Omega})=e^{-jr\Omega}$ ($r$ not integer) you get

$$h(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{j\Omega (n-r)}d\Omega=\frac{1}{2\pi j(n-r)}\left(e^{j\pi (n-r)}-e^{-j\pi (n-r)}\right)=\frac{\sin\pi(n-r)}{\pi (n-r)}$$

So you get a sampled sinc function shifted by $r$.

Comment: Hmm.. The DTFT pairs table I was using listed $\delta[n-n_0]$ as the inverse of $e^{-j\omega n_0}$ and not sinc...

Comment: @Sanuuu: Yes, but only because $n_0$ is assumed to be integer! If you get a function that is not in your table you simply have to compute the inverse transform yourself.

Comment: @Sanuuu: In the formula I showed in my answer, you can also assume $r$ to be integer. Then $h(n)$ is zero for all $n\neq r$ (because the sine is $0$ at integer multiples of $\pi$), and $h(n)$ is $1$ for $n=r$ (the limit of the sinc function for zero argument). This is exactly what your table says for *integer* delays.